# Trigger Calculation between two fields from different sObjects

Tags: trigger, sobject, update, insert

I am new to apex. I have two objects blood_bank__c and patient__c.
I want to change quantity of blood in blood bank after patient is given some blood. This trigger is not working, and its not allowing me to add new patient.

trigger :

```
trigger bloodcalTrigger on patient__c ( after update, after insert) {

patient__c tok = [ Select blood_quantity_used__c, Blood_group_del__c From patient__c];
blood_bank__c cons = [Select quantity__c, name From blood_bank__c];


          if(tok.Blood_group_del__c == cons.name )  {
   cons.quantity__c = cons.quantity__c - tok.blood_quantity_used__c ;

   }else {}

}
```

Comment: What is the relationship between these two objects? What type of field is Blood_group_del__c?  Can you please update the question with these details.

Comment: I would create an object that is detail to blood bank and patient called transfusions. Then use roll up summaries and formulas. Having a single field on patient does not seem sufficient as it is only good for a single transfusion and provides no detail. Suggest you look at object model before trigger. You may also want another object named donations related to blood bank

Answer (score 0):

You are not having any DML statement that your blood_bank__c record is updated.

Try

`cons.quantity__c = cons.quantity__c - tok.blood_quantity_used__c ;
update cons;`

However, you assume that you only have one blood bank in the system. You should try to also update

`blood_bank__c cons = [Select quantity__c, name From blood_bank__c];`

to something like

`blood_bank__c cons = [Select quantity__c, name From blood_bank__c WHERE name = :tok.Blood_group_del__c];`

If you need more help, we need additional information about your data structure.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesnt work.
Moreover ....  After my triggger is active, I cant add new patient to database. it shows an error saying- "Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger bloodcalTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: bloodcalTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject: Trigger.bloodcalTrigger: line 6, column 1"

Comment: This is exactly what I meant by _"However, you assume that you only have one blood bank in the system."_ Your query returns more than one result, and you are trying to assign multiple results to one sObject.
We need more information about your data structure - how many blood banks are in the system? Is it possible that multiple blood banks have the same name?